# NextJS specific dynamic routes

Tags: next.js, url-routing

I'm building a small application and want to build a simple routing system but I got into a small issue.

I have my `category` page which is dynamic, and a single post which will be `category/post-name` now I want that my `category` page to be only accessible when the user goes to `website.com/category1/` or `website.com/category2/` or `website.com/category3/` but not on other dynamic routes.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Predefined routes take precedence over dynamic routes, and dynamic routes over catch all routes. For example:

1. `pages/category/category1.js` - Will match `/category/category1`
2. `pages/category/caregory2.js` - Will match `/category/category2`
3. `pages/category/category3.js` - Will match `/category/category3`
4. `pages/category/[category_id].js` - Will match `/category/category4`, `/category/category5`, etc. But not `/category/category1`, `/category/category2`, `/category/category3`.